# multiple conditions in excel filter using c#

Tags: c#, excel

How can I apply multiple criteria for excel filter using C#?

```
string[] crit = new string[] {"DA","DB","DC"}; 
wsht.Range["A1:D20"].AutoFilter(1, crit,Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlOr, Type.Missing, true);
```

But this only filters the `DC` option.

Thanks!!

Comment: You haven't provided much detail here. For example, what is 'lastRow'? I would guess that it is 'C' which is probably why this is only filtering the 'DC' option.

Comment: hi, lastRow is just a variable to denote range. i have edited it. I did not get your point!